# Get commit date of a given SHA1 (submodules) commit

Tags: git, git-submodules

very special problem: I have integrated submodules and I get my submodules 8-char long referenced commit state by

```
$ git ls-tree HEAD MY_SUBMODULE | awk '{print $3}' | cut -c -8
03B446AB
```

Now I want to get the commit date of the submodule, preferably in format yyyy-mm-dd. Do you have a idea how to handle this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`git show`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-show) command (for the committer date):

```
git --git-dir=/path/to/submodule/.git show --format="%ci" <commit>
```

The [OP John Rumpel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1020719/john-rumpel) suggests [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15107545/get-commit-date-of-a-given-sha1-submodules-commit/15107824#comment21310088_15107824):

```
git --git-dir=path/to/submodule/.git show --pretty=format:'%ad' --date=short <commit> 
# or
git log --git-dir=path/to/submodule/.git --pretty=format:'%ad %h' --date=short | grep <commit>
```

Comment: thanks, but: unrecognized argument: /path/to/submodule/.git (replaced by my specific path)

Comment: @JohnRumpel sorry, the `--git-dir` option must follow directly `git`, not `git show`. I have fixed that typo.

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice solution. Handled it much more sophisticated via git log | grep | awk

Comment: Well, two solutions: 1) git --git-dir=path/to/submodule/.git show --pretty=format:'%ad' --date=short <commit> 2) git log --git-dir=path/to/submodule/.git --pretty=format:'%ad %h' --date=short | grep <commit>

Comment: @JohnRumpel interesting. I have edited my answer to include those two solutions.